# Google App Engine app.yaml for PHP scripts

Tags: php, google-app-engine, url, app.yaml

I'm trying to get my `app.yaml` file to send URLs as one would expect them to work. Currently, my `app.yaml` file looks as such:

```
handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

  # Serve php scripts.
- url: /(.+\.php)
  script: \1

- url: /.*
  script: main.php
```

This works ok. I go to a `URL`, click a link and it redirects and loads the page properly. The problem is when I try to access a `.php` file that isn't there. It gives me a warning and a bunch of errors. I would like this to redirect to a specific page, such as a log in page or 404 page. Any idea on how to do that? Thanks!

Comment: Go read here on how to handle error codes: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/appconfig#Custom_Error_Responses

Comment: Thanks! Got it working! I didn't notice that section before.

Answer (score 1):

This yaml file is:

1) configured to direct any filepath ending in `.php` to the corresponding file. eg. the URL `\bellows.php` will be redirected to the file `<my_app_directory>\bellows.php`

2) any URL not matching the above rule will be redirected to `<my_app_directory>/main.php`

Thus when you hit any URL that doesn't end in .php it will redirect to main.php - this is likely what is generating the errors.